# Join tables according to one value in common: can't get to work

Tags: html, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables like this:

```
Tables       Students            Posts

           |COMMENT|ID|      |PROGRAMME|ID|
           |   x1  |1 |      |Finance  |2 |
           |   x2  |2 |      |Mgmt     |3 |
           |   x3  |3 |      |History  |1 |
```

And I would like an SQL Statement to join the two tables and yield two according columns COMMENT and PROGRAMME of comments and programmes that have the same ID:

```
           |COMMENT|PROGRAMME|      
           |   x1  | History |     
           |   x2  | Finance |      
           |   x3  | Mgmt    |
```

I have tried different statements like:

```
SELECT s.Programme FROM Students s, Posts ss where s.ID = ss.Id
```

but only seem to get one column in return. This statement, for instance, leads to:
               | History |
               |Finance  |
               | Mgmt    |

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Add the query which you can't get to work.

Comment: You will increase the change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Seems this

```
select a.COMMENT, b.PROGRAMME from Students as  a join Posts as b on a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: that won't work because b.programme is in the table Posts.
I've added the query I have tried above

Comment: Show the error please because b.programme is from Post as b.. Be sure you have poste the correct column and table name in questions..

Comment: The little fiddle shows that it DOES work, see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/173a4/1). Or what else do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the `COMMENT` column from the Students table with the joined `PROGRAMME` column from the Posts table. Because I used an `INNER JOIN` there have to be results in both tables. If e.g. you want also the comments where the `PROGRAMME` is `NULL` then you can choose to use a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT s.COMMENT
    , p.PROGRAMME
FROM Students AS s
    INNER JOIN Posts AS p
        ON s.ID = p.ID
```